# Do we get -1 Reputation when we downvote a post? If so why?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, up-votes

I was under review where I found some posts of low quality and downvoted them. When I saw my reputation sometime later, it was down and in details it was because I downvoted few posts. Can anyone explain the logic behind this?

[image]

Comment: The logic is that it's supposed to hurt a little when you downvote (answers only).

Answer (score 9):

It is to make you think twice about downvoting.

This only applies to downvoting answers though - not questions.

For the most part, if you downvote something of low quality, it usually gets deleted and you get your point back. This is what happened in the screenshot you posted.